# dom references and global variables localization. does it make sense?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, backbone-views

Does it make more efficient to make a local( and private ) variables / DOM references if you use them in backbone view?

```
var app = {};

(function( window, document ) {
  var variable = 'some data';
  var dom_reference = document.getElementById('some-id');

  app.view = Backbone.View.extend({
    // some action
  });
})( window, document );
```

Comment: If it saves your from requerying the DOM multiple times in your code then it would make sense. Otherwise, there's no point in keeping references just to keep references.

Comment: `var dom-reference` is a syntax error, in case that's not obvious.

Comment: hm, two questions 1) why you dont define this var inside view `initialize` as until view is inited there is no need in any DOM ? 2) Is there any reason you don't use RequireJS ?

Comment: dont want to reinitialize in every function of the view. though... i can put those in those inside of render-function... hmmm....

Comment: why on every function, only once on initialization...if u put it in `render` you will reset var on every render. Plus set such things as DOM nodes vars bette rdo on init, as you cant be sure that no other code or view has already removed this node.

Comment: or keep it in constructor like this `var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    variable: 'some data',
    dom_reference: document.getElementById('some-id')
})` also u can use native Backbone `el` to keep link to DOM node

Comment: in this case i have to use `this`/`self` in every function that i want to avoid - makes code longer messier etc